# Adding custom posts into avada wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have installed and used a plugin called: Custom Post Type Maker. With this, I have created custom posts, in this case recipes. How do I now display these recipes or add them in like a custom post type with Avada? On my home page I would like to display them with similar settings to the blog post.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [paid plugin](https://codecanyon.net/item/custom-post-types-and-taxonomies-for-fusion-builder/15572585) that extends Avada Builder for displaying Custom Post Type content. I searched but couldn't find a free alternative to that.

Comment: thank, yes I have tried this one too, but it doesn't seem very easy to use. For example, once installed, how do I add these custom posts? https://codecanyon.net/item/custom-post-types-and-taxonomies-for-fusion-builder/15572585

Comment: It is very easy to create and add custom posts with this free plugin. https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/